# Change Tomcat Webapp directory from code

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, path

I have a `Webapp` running on **Tomcat**. This app has an entry `Servlet` which receives a certain parameter. It looks like this:

```
https://localhost:8443/myapp/entryservlet?param=app1
```

This parameter `param` indicates which webapp should be loaded.

In my Webapp directory I have a structure like this:

```
-WebApp
  -- App1
  -- App2
  -- App3
     ...
```

Depending on the parameter, I have to tell Tomcat which webapp should be loaded

Comment: What do you mean by "loaded". Tomcat loads webapps, not you. Perhaps you mean to -redirect- to a specific deployed webapp?

Comment: Yes! sorry but the words confusion! It's just what are you saying... Redirect Tomcatt to any of the webapps depending on the param received

Comment: ... so that's it? You are asking how to perform a redirect in a servlet? Well lucky you, you can do a search in SO and get many existing questions with answers.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why but I was thinking about a another solution more difficult than this...I was obscured!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, you're not passing in the entire URL as a parameter, but here's a sample redirecting to another url.  You can also look at forwarding.

```
public class EntryServlet extends HttpServlet {

   public final void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response
   ) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String forwardURL = request.getParameter("param");
    response.sendRedirect( forwardURL );
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why but I was thinking about a another solution more difficult than this...I was obscured!